# Pass generics class to an annotation

Tags: java

In the testing framework I'm using, there is a `Precondition` annotation that takes a class and calls `call()` method in it at runtime.

## Core Modules of the Testing Framework:

#### Precondition Annotation

```
public @interface Precondition {
    Class<? extends Scriptlet<? extends Context>> scriptlet();
    String value() default Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
}
```

#### Scriptlet

```
public interface Scriptlet<V> extends Callable<V> {
}
```

#### Context

```
public interface Context {
}
```

---

If I pass the following precondition class to `Precondition` annotation there will be no errors.

#### CommonContextInit precondition class

```
class CommonContextInit implements Scriptlet<DataModel>{

    CommonContextInit(Object script,String value){  
    }

    @override
    public DataModel call() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Script

```
@Precondition(scriptlet=CommonContextInit.class)
```

But I want to make `CommonContextInit` a generic where user can pass the type of the scriptlet so I changed the `CommonContextInit` class as follows

#### CommonContextInit precondition class

```
class CommonContextInit<T extends Context> implements Scriptlet<T>{

    CommonContextInit(Object script,String value){  
    }

    @override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the issue here is I have no idea how to pass the class to `Precondition`. The following I have tried but looks like it's totally invalid syntax.

```
// ERROR: The annotation @Precondition is disallowed for this location.
@Precondition(scriptlet=CommonContextInit<DataModel>.class)
```

How should I pass the `Class` of `CommonContextInit<DataModel>` to `Precondition`?

Comment: CommonContextInit<DataModel>.class in itself is wrong and you shall get identifier expected. You shall pass the "actual" instance of the class that extends CommonContextInit and its created e.g ChildCommonContextInit.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend my comment you shall have something like

```
class DataModelInstance extends CommonContextInit<DataModel>  implements Scriptlet<DataModel>{
    DataModelInstance(Object script,String value){  
        super(script, value);
    }
    //other overrides
}
```

and then call `@Precondition(scriptlet=DataModelInstance.class)`